# I want to change name on train ticket to another friend

Tags: trains, tickets, india

I want to change the name of the passenger on my booked train ticket from Sulekha to Gayatree for the journey to Pune. Is this possible, if so, how?

Comment: And what’s the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can only transfer ticket to your close relatives. For friends, its not applicable.

https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/allahabad/Now-you-can-transfer-your-train-ticket-to-your-loved-ones/articleshow/7845239.cms